# Few solutions for $a_1+a_2=n$ implies few solutions to $2a_1+a_2=n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, additive-combinatorics

Let $\mathscr{A}\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ be an infinite subset of $\mathbb{N}$, and suppose
$$ s(n) := |\{(a_1,a_2)\in \mathscr{A}^2 : a_1+a_2 = n\}|$$
is *uniformly bounded* for every $n$ (that is, there is $M>0$ s.t. $s(n) < M,\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$).

> Does this implies that the number of solutions to
>   $$ 2a_1+a_2 = n,\quad a_1,a_2 \in\mathscr{A} $$
>   is also uniformly bounded for all $n$?

I think it might be false, but I'm having trouble coming up with a counterexample. I thought some [IP set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_set) could provide such example (e.g. $\{n:n\text{ has only $1$s on its $3$-adic expansion}\}$), but I think IP sets in general does not even satisfy the premise.

I also tried a couple of things to prove it true (like considering $\hat{a}_1+2\hat{a}_2=m$ and adding both equations), but it didn't work. Any hints?

Comment: Can you give an example of $\mathscr{A}$ such that $s(n)$ be uniformly bounded, please?

Comment: @Piquito: any Sidon set (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidon_sequence) does the job.

Comment: Than you very much. I confess I can not find an example myself.

Comment: @Piquito $\mathscr{A}=(k^n)_{n\geqslant 0}$ are examples of Sidon sets. I think "larger" Sidon sets involves more elaborated constructions (like taking cubes and "sifting" some elements in a smart way), but I'm not very familiar with those explicit examples too :)

Answer (score 2):

There are sets such that solutions to $a+b = n$ are bounded by $1$ and solutions to $2a+b=n$ are unbounded.

Suppose you have a finite set $\mathcal A$ of size $k$ and a large integer $N$. If you try to add a pair $(a,N-2a)$ without making a redundancy to equations $a+b=n$, you have at most only $2k^3+2k^2$ forbidden values for $a$.

In particular, if $2(k+2m-1)^3 + 2(k+2m-1)^2 < (N-2)/2$ then you have enough room to pick $m$ pairs in a row.

Now to build a set such that forall $m$ there is a $N_m$ such that $2a+b = N_m$ has at least $m$ solutions, you can simply pick $N_m > 2+4[(k+2m-1)^3+(k+2m-1)^2]$ where $k=2+4+\ldots+(2m-2)$ and choose the pairs one at a time.

Comment: Hmm, that seems interesting! But I didn't quite understood the $2k^3+2k^2$ bound. Also, how these additions will not mess up the solutions to $\{a+b=n\}$? In picking $m$ such pairs in a row, doesn't it add solutions to a specific number? (e.g. taking $\{12,14,16,18,20,22\}$ it adds $6$ sols. to $a+b=34$)

Comment: whenever you add a pair, it adds a few more forbidden values for the choice of the next pairs, of course you have to take those into account for making the next choices.

Comment: And there always is finitely many forbidden values because you can only make up finitely many equations of the form $x+y = z+t$ where some of them are in the old set and some of them are $a$ or $N-2a$, and those have at most one solution for $a$.